# Replace findDOMNode with ref

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-dom, react-ref

Can someone please help me understand how to use ref in place of `findDOMNode`?
I'm trying to reference a d3 object and originally did so using `findDOMNode` but I'm getting warning that this is deprecated. Please see my code below:

```
class Node extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.d3Node = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this))
      .datum(this.props.data)
      .call(FORCE.enterNode)
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.d3Node.datum(this.props.data)
      .call(FORCE.updateNode)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <g className='node'>
        <circle onClick={this.props.addLink}/>
        <text>{this.props.data.name}</text>
      </g>
    );
  }
}

export default Node;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to use refs docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```js
class Node extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.gRef = React.createRef()
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.d3Node = d3.select(this.gRef.current)
      .datum(this.props.data)
      .call(FORCE.enterNode)
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.d3Node.datum(this.props.data)
      .call(FORCE.updateNode)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <g className='node' ref={this.gRef}>
        <circle onClick={this.props.addLink}/>
        <text>{this.props.data.name}</text>
      </g>
    );
  }
}

export default Node;
```